# how to put thumbnail below category's title?

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails

Edit : ok everything works fine : i finally had to use taxonomies and get_terms, and putting everything in divs work better than lis. Thanks for your help.

Hi,
i have a problem with the categories and post thumbnail, my images are mixing up, the titles are OK, in the good order, but then the thumbnail of the first category goes under the second category title, and the second category thumbnail goes under the first title. I tried with "orderby" "name" on both `get_categories` or `$second` query but it's still the same : do you know how i could fix it?

```
        <?php
                        <div id="cat-diapo">
                    <ul>
                        <?php 
                        //$tout = wp_list_categories();
                        $tout = get_categories();
                        foreach ($tout as $tou){
                            $mon_id = $tou->cat_ID;
                            echo '<li>';
                            echo '<span>'.$tou->name.'</span>';
                            $argu = array ('cat'=>$mon_id);
                            $second = new WP_Query($argu);
                            while ($second->have_posts()) : $second->the_post();
                                $res = '<div class="sous-cat">'.the_post_thumbnail("mini", array("alt"=> the_post()->ID)).'</div>';
                            endwhile;
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                        }
                        echo '</li>';
```

and here's the markup :

```
        <div id="cat-diapo">

        <ul>

        <li><span>Andalousia</span>
        <img width="150" height="140" src="http://localhost:8888/espe/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/h.jpg" class="attachment-mini wp-post-image" alt="" title="h" />

        <li><span>Spain</span>
        <img width="150" height="123" src="http://localhost:8888/espe/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Corida-65x811.jpg" class="attachment-mini wp-post-image" alt="" title="Corida - 65x81" />

        <li><span>Another post</span>
        <img width="150" height="213" src="http://localhost:8888/espe/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/p2-150x213.jpg" class="attachment-mini wp-post-image" alt="" title="p2" /></li>
```

So all the code php in my first post is wrapped by "ul" tags, and this gives me the code just above : this seems ok, but the image of "Andalousia" is under the title "Spain", and vice versa...

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be generating broken markup by mixing stuff in and out of list item (`<li></li>`) tags. Try validating resulting markup and fix any errors produced.

Comment: thanks, what do you mean by "Try validating resulting markup and fix any errors produced" ? i checked the source code : everything seems ok, except only images are switching

Comment: @Paul_p with tools such as http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/ for example.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it did not show me any specific error. Do you know any test i could make to debug this?

Comment: @Paul_p if you add sample of resulting markup to question that might help figuring out the issue you are having

Comment: i put the code in the post below